# Can I replace norming in the martingale CLT by the conditional variance?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, soft-question, martingales

Consider the following setup: Let $\{S_n, \mathcal{F}_n: n \geq 1\}$ 
 be a martingale on a probability space $\{\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P}\}$, with $S_0 = 0$ and differences $X_n = S_n - S_{n-1}$ for $n = 1, 2, \ldots$

Define the following:
$$ \sigma_n^2 = E(X_n^2 | \mathcal{F}_{n-1}), \quad V_n^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i^2, \quad s_n^2 = E V_n^2 $$

In all the martingale CLT literature I've seen (such that [this one](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoms/1177693494)), there's usually some requirement like:

> (1) Throughout, we consider martingales for which $V_n^2 s_n^{-2} \to 1$ in probability as $n \to \infty$.

And then under this LLN-like condition for the conditional variance, the final result is that the martingale $S_n$, **when normalized by $s_n$**, is asymptotically normal.

**My question:** what happens if instead of norming by $s_n$, I use $V_n$ instead? I'm looking at a particular application where I actually can compute $V_n$ but not $s_n$. Does using $V_n$ break something fundamental about the CLT and, if so, is there an easy way to see it?

Comment: Basically the fluctuations of $V_n^2$ around their means become small compared to the means themselves. So that is a bit restrictive, but you need some analogue of LLN if you hope to get an analogue of CLT, no?

Comment: @gogurt  Something wrong with your definition of $\sigma_n^{2}$. According to this definition martingale property gives $\sigma_n=0$ for all $n$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy oops. fixed!

Comment: @Ian: Hmm. I'm not sure I follow your point about having an analogue of the LLN. Where I'm struggling is thinking about how this LLN argument applied to the conditional variances intersects with the CLT on the original martingale sequence. Can you elaborate?